# Why Extension methods?

Tags: c#

Many of the BCL Classes have Methods and ExtensionMethods. What is the design decision to pick ExtensionMethods over Methods when Microsoft has the source code of their Class?
Thank you,
Smith

Comment: Because while Microsoft has the source code... we don't.

Comment: When they have source code they can add additional methods instead of making it extension methods. Why they choose to add extension methods to BCL Classes?

Comment: @LaysomeSmith: Example please?  All the extension methods I know of in the BCL offhand are on interfaces, not on classes.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx

Comment: See my comment below, those extension methods apply to all of `IEnumerable<T>`, not just `string`.  Thus it's not an extension method on `string`, per se, but on all `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces (`string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually most of the extension methods in the BCL apply not to classes, but to interfaces, which is a key power of extension methods.

For example, almost all of LINQ to objects is implemented as extensions to the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, and not to the classes `List<T>, HashSet<T>`, etc.

Because interfaces do not have functionality (just a contract), adding an extension method to a interface gives you a way to an interface itself.  This is especially handy when the implementation need only know of the interface for it's use and not implementation specifics (per se).

Microsoft *does* add new methods in their BCL classes all the time (though of course they avoid breaking changes wherever possible).  But I believe the majority of their extension method use in the BCL is on interfaces and not for adding functionality that could easily be added with a new method directly to the class/struct.

So, in short, when Microsoft chooses to add functionality to a single `class` (or family with a common base class), they'd probably just add the method directly (all things being equal), but if they wanted to apply a new method to all implementations of a given interface, they'd probably use an extension method on that interface.

Also keep in mind this!  Because Microsoft gave us extension methods, it applies to classes they didn't create as well!  For example, any class that you create that implements `IEnumerable<T>` gets the functionality of LINQ as well as a bonus, even though you inherit no common base classes, etc.

Comment: @LaysomeSmith: Those extension methods are there because of `IEnumerable<T>`, remember that `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.  Click on most of them and you'll see that they apply to `IEnumerable<TSource>`, not `string` directly...

Comment: Whatever. They could have added all these extension methods as methods? Is it not possible at all to implement these extension method as methods for Microsoft?

Comment: @LaysomeSmith: Keep in mind what you are suggesting, that would be in essence copying the same code into every class that wants to use it.  That would be a massive duplication of code and would be a maintenance nightmare.  Most of those classes that implement `IEnumerable<T>` do not share common base classes, so the only way to get it in most ofthem would be to duplicate.  Thus extension methods are clearly more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the design decision to pick ExtensionMethods over Methods

One strong reason to pick extension method in my opinion is that it promotes the Open/Closed principal of SOLID i.e. open for extension close for modification

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft tends to use extension methods for functionality that will apply to a broad array of different code bases.  For example, LINQ is implemented almost entirely as extension methods.  (and most, if not all of the methods you point out are generic LINQ methods, not specific to those classes).

This has many advantages.  First, if you're not using LINQ, you don't have to include a reference to the LINQ libraries, or a using.  This reduces code bloat.

Second, LINQ can apply to any object that implements IEnumerable, including your own code if you implement an enumerator.  You don't have to write this code like you would have to otherwise.

Third, it allows for functionality to be broken up into discrete units, creating a better seperation of concerns and making the classes more maintainable.

There are a lot of other potential benefits as well, but this list should suffice to make it clear that Extension methods were the best way to implement these methods.